# try, catch not working An unhandled exception of type 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll

Tags: c#, wpf

So I'm working on a simple browser to teach myself c# and everything was working fine, then I ran the thing to show someone and it came up with the error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll
>
> Additional information: 'The invocation of the constructor on type 'Browser.MainWindow' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception.' Line number '4' and line position '56'.

In the cs file there obviously references at 4, 56 but in the xaml file 4, 56 was:

```
xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
```

I looked every where and saw to add a `try/catch` block to the `InitiateComponent()` like this:

```
try
{
    InitializeComponent();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("ERROR:" + ex.InnerException.Message);
}
```

And it does not spit anything starting with "ERROR: " so I assume the try/catch isn't catching anything, which is weird because the error talks about problems when creating MainWindow.

//Probably very valuable information I forgot to mention

EDIT:  it started happening around the time i switched the target framework from 4.5.1 to 4.0 to it would work on my friends vista computer. (I went through the steps to correctly switch over)

Comment: Could you post your xaml? The problem is probably in there.

Comment: Does your `Browser.MainWindow` class have a parameterless constructor?

Comment: this problem is often Occured in InitializeComponent,check your InitializeComponent and find is there something called before Application object was fully constructed.

Comment: is it possible for you to post a working sample which have this issue, I suspect this is not the right place to look for the mentioned exception.

Comment: If the base type's constructor throws an exception, where are you going to catch it? At any rate, look at line number '4' and line position '56' in `MainWindow.xaml`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using Awesomium as an htlm ui engine for the browser and when I switched target frameworks, it changed my platform configuration back to Any CPU, which the Awesomium wiki said it needs to be x86. Once I switch to that everything works fine.

Answer (score 1):

No one here can help you to fix your actual problem without seeing your code. However, whenever you see a `System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException`, you should ignore that and look into its inner `Exception`. The `XamlParseException` is just used as the actual `Exception` is passed through the XAML layer.

Next, whenever you see an error like:

> The invocation of the constructor on type 'AppName.WindowName' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception

... you can kind of ignore this message as well, as it is fairly generic and unhelpful

All this actually means is that you have an error somewhere in your code... yeah, I know... very unhelpful. However, one of the absolute best ways to fix this problem is to simply undo the last few edits that you made, build the project and run it again. 9 out of 10 times, this will fix the issue... on the 10th time, you may need to undo more steps, but essentially, this should do the trick.

Comment: So if i can't undo it because the program has been closed since the time the problem started occuring, theres no fix? And it started happening around the time i switched the target framework from 4.5.1 to 4.0 to it would work on my friends vista computer.